# Как скроллить список, состоящий из ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-linearlayout

У меня есть LinearLayout, в котором находятся ImageView, расположенные в один столбик. Но все ImageView в экран не влазят. Такой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы я мог скроллить LinearLayout вниз, чтобы увидеть все ImageView?

```
private void someFunc() {
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.main);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainLayout.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    mainlayout.addView(imageView);

   // и таких ImageView у меня несколько, они не влезают в LinearLayout
}
```

Я использовал LinearLayout, потому что все объекты в этом layout находятся в столбик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Засунуть LinearLayout в [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout ...>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: У меня есть одна проблема в Linearlayout. Когда у меня появляется 3-ий ImageView, то первый ImageView удаляется.

Comment: Но эта тема для отдельного вопроса.